# Selecting data from multiple mysql tables that all share the same index but not data structure

Tags: mysql

I have 5 "event" tables. They each have different data, however all share 2 identical fields: "mission_id" "mission_tick"

I would like to perform a single query to get the data from all of these tables WHERE mission_id = x and ORDER BY mission_tick.

I cannot use UNION as they have different number of columns, and there are too many to manually do "as null" for every column that might not match. Ideally I'd like to avoid duplication of columns names too. For example 4/5 tables all have a "type" column.

`(SELECT * FROM events_downed WHERE mission = 12)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM events_get_in_out WHERE mission = 12)`

Comment: Have you considered using a `JOIN`?

Comment: Yes, a LEFT JOIN seems to mash results from each table together in each row, with different mission_time duplications in the same row also.

Comment: Have you tried a LEFT JOIN using DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned it, you cannot use `UNION` because "they have different number of columns" and in fact you will not be able to write a query to fetch data from different tables with different columns.

At best you can use `CONCAT` or `CONCAT_WS` to group all the "different" columns together in one column but the result will be hard to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    (SELECT mission_tick, CONCAT_WS(' ', col1, col2, col3...) FROM events_downed WHERE mission = 12)
    UNION
    (SELECT mission_tick, CONCAT_WS(' ', col1, col2, col3...) FROM events_get_in_out WHERE mission = 12)
) as x
ORDER BY mission_tick;
```

> Ideally I'd like to avoid duplication of columns names too. For example 4/5 tables all have a "type" column.

This is not possible if all tables don't have that column.

In your situation the best option is most likely to write separate queries, one for each table.